# Why is Spring Security antmatcher is always returning unauthorized?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to learn Spring Security and have created a simple controller. I want to enable POST to /all endpoint for unauthorized users and POST to /user for users that have the USER role. For some reason my code is always returning 403 unauthorized.

Controller

```
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> all() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("all", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> user() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("user", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/all").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").hasRole("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using spring boot? If so, what version?.

Comment: I am using spring boot version 2.1.3 RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Provide a way to authenticate (example: `httpBasic()`)
- Provide a PasswordEncoder (example: `BCryptPasswordEncoder`)

Putting it all together, your configuration should look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/all").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").hasRole("USER")
            .and().httpBasic();
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
           .withUser("user")
           .password(encoder().encode("user"))
           .roles("USER");
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }
}
```